# Nested fragment problems on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have this situation.

1. A drawer layout -> each section is a fragment
2. A section contain a page viewer (3 fragments )
3. Each fragment contains a recyclerview and each item is a fragment

I have some problems.

1. When the orientation of the screen changes i move always to the first fragment of the page adapter.
2. If i write something in one of these fragments and the sceeen orientation change lose everything.
3. Same problems with onPause etc.
   How can I manage this situation?
   thanks.

Comment: any solutions to this ? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the you are using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`/`getSupportFragmentMAnager()` inside a nested Fragment.

Comment: yes i use getChildFragmentManager but what should i do if for example i am in the second page of page viewer in the 5th element. I rotate the screen and the activity will destroy and after recreate. So, How can i say well, i was in the second page and inside the 5th element?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's will be helpful. Just paste it in your AndroidManifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">`
inside activity of your AndroidManifest.xml 
and
adding this to every fragment is working fine for me.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: of course the answer is not so easy. otherwise i would not created this question.. but thanks